# Is the function $f(x) = \sum_{n\geq 1 } \cos(n^2 x ) / n^{2.6}$ absolutely continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, fourier-analysis

It is of course continuous.

Here the exponent $2.6 $ is delibrately chosen to be bigger than $2.5$.

If we differentiate the series formally term-by-term, we will get

$$   - \sum_n \frac{\sin n^2 x }{n^{0.6}} . $$

This series is at least in the $L^2 $ space. That is why a number bigger than $2.5$ is chosen.  But I am not sure whether it is convergent. If in the numerator, it were $n$ in stead of $n^2$, it is convergent by the Dirichlet test.

Comment: Absolutely continuous : $f = \int g(x)dx$ with $g \in L^1_{loc}$. And $L^2_{loc}\subset L^1_{loc}$. Did you mean asking if $f'$ is bounded ?

Comment: I see. You used cauchy-schwarz theorem.

Comment: I do not care whether $f'$ is bounded. But that could be a good question too.

Comment: I used that $\int_0^{2\pi} |g(x)|dx = \int_0^{2\pi} |g(x)|1_{|g|\le 1}dx+\int_0^{2\pi} |g(x)|1_{|g|> 1}dx\le 2\pi + \int_0^{2\pi} |g(x)|^2 1_{|g|> 1}dx \le 2\pi + \int_0^{2\pi} |g(x)|^2dx$ where $g(x) = - \sum_n \frac{\sin n^2 x }{n^{0.6}} \in L^2([0,2\pi])$. Since the series for $g$ converges in $L^2([0,2\pi])$ it converges in $L^1([0,2\pi])$ and we can integrate term by term to recover $f$

Comment: $\sum_n \frac{\sin n^2 x }{n^{0.6}}$ is convergent a.e. by an useful theorem (superseeded by Carleson's famous deep result about Fourier series of $L^2$ functions, but almost elementary to prove from basic theory of Fourier series), namely that if $\Sigma{(a_n^2+b_n^2)(\log n)^2} < \infty$, then $\Sigma{(a_n\cos(nx)+b_n\sin(nx)})$ converges a.e. and the last condition is obviously satisfied here

Comment: Also, though deeper than the above (but much less deep than Carleson), sits a result of Hardy-Littlewood about trigonometric series related to the $\theta$ functions of which $\sum_n \frac{\sin n^2 x }{n^{0.6}}$ is one by partial summation, namely that $\sum_{k=1}^{n}{e^{i\pi k^2 x}}=O(n^{\frac{1}{2}}(\log n))$ for almost all irrational $x$